# Alert text when submit detected

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit

In a function called `outputProducts` I have added a submit button to my table:

```
$(addToCartCell).append("<input type='submit' id='addToCart' value='Add To Cart'>");
```

In order to check the submit button was pressed I make another function:

```
function addToCart()
{
    $(#addToCart).submit(function() {
        alert('Submit Detected.');
    });
}
```

But this isn't working and the table created in the function before doesnt even show up, but when I get rid of the addToCart function it does.

Comment: Use click() instead, the submit() is for form element
 $(#addToCart).click(function() {

Comment: Bro just to mention your code aint right, you are not providing all the code associated - see here how `submit` is used man - http://api.jquery.com/submit/ hope this helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a syntax error, instead of `$(#addToCart)` you need `$('#addToCart')`.

Besides that, you need to bind the `submit` event to the **form**, not the submit button (you'd bind `click` to the button, but since you want to do something on submit, binding the submit event to the form is the way to go).

If you do not have a form, use `type="button"` since there's nothing to submit anyway and bind a `click` event to the button.

If you need to bind the event *before* the button exists, use a delegate. `#container` should be an element that already exists and is a parent of the button:

```
$('#container').on('click', '#addToCart', function() { ... });
```

And since you seem to have multiple products, remember that **IDs have to be unique** - so if you have more than one button, use a class instead and change the selector to `.addToCart` accordingly.

Comment: I dont have a form, this is just a input button in a table

Comment: @Ryan Murphy so you should use `click` instead of `submit`.

Comment: If you don't have a form you shouldn't use `type="submit"` button but simply `type="button"` - and yes, bind `click` in that case.

Comment: The problem is im using `.each` to loop through an array, producing 10 rows, and each row has a button saying `add to cart`. if i change to button and also to `.click` then if i click the first row the alert appears but not for the other rows.

Comment: Class thing solved it. Jeepers, greats help and thank you so much. Just learning jquery and loving it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error. Try `$('#addToCart')`.

Comment: please be more extensive in your answers

Answer (score -1):

please try the following code

```
function addToCart()
{
    $("#addToCart").live("submit", (function() {
        alert('Submit Detected.');
    });
}
```

Note: i have tried the same but since you have added the element at runtime you need to bind the event to the element.

Comment: If he binds it after creating the button he doesn't need live events. Besides that, binding a submit event on a button makes no sense.

Comment: ok no issues even i was not much clear, but i was aware that input is added to html at runtime which needs binding of event.